# Installing SSL Certificate breaks PHP on WIMP

Tags: windows, php, wimp

We have a web and several subwebs running on a W2K3 Standard server. Everything was working fine. SSL was set to expire so we purchased a new certificate and updated the one subweb handling secure traffic. One web was running PHP 5.2.17 and the secure web with the certificate was running PHP 4.? (for backward compatibility reasons.) Now PHP on both webs does not work. Specifically on the PHP 5 web when I hit a PHP page even as simple as a echo "hello world"; it gives the error "invalid access to memory location." The PHP 4 site when hit will give the message "The specified procedure could not be found." Among the solutions tried: restart affected webs, restart IIS, restart server, verified mapping for .php points to php5isapi.dll, removed and added extensions for both PHP 4 and 5 (and verified both were set to allowed), recycled application pools. Not seeing anything in the Win log files nor if I tell PHP INI to output to a text log file. Is there anything short of reinstalling PHP that can be done? The "only" change was that the new cert was installed, which we reinstalled the old one just to rule out the new cert being the issue. I say "only" because I am sure that did something but I am out of things to try.

Answer (score 0):

I found some resources on web referring to downgrade PHP solve this problem:

http://lijumathew.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/php-throws-an-error-on-iis-invalid-access-to-memory-location/

I would like to ask you for some details.Is your W2K3 server standard or enterprise edition?
32bit or 64bit?

Thanks.

Comment: W2K3 Standard 32-bit. I did see that blog post but I questioned it as a solution for my situation because PHP worked before. If I never had it working prior to updating the certificate I would pursue that direction. Also, if I ws to update I would probably go with the most current.

Comment: Maybe you should rise a ticket on bugs.php.net.Most recent version should not be the best solution.Good example is Redhat Enterpise OS releases.Plese try to downgrade, just for test.And one thing to note, can you compare parameters of previous and current certificate? (key lenght, algs, provider, etc..) Thanks.

Comment: I didn't actually do the cert install so I don't have all info but I do know that the providers were different. They went from a more expensive one to a cheaper (although still well known) cert. I didn't see a PHP setting that would ask for specific type of cert though?